# Using curl to send unsafe url characters in request url

Tags: http, curl

I am sending a curl request pointing to an url containing unsafe characters in it like `/test/#/test1.html`

I tried below possible ways but was not working. The Url ends when it sees a `#` in it and the remaining part is not processed. I took a packet capture and found that the url which is sent by curl is just `http://<someIP>testsite/` and not `http://<someIP>testsite/#/file.html`

```
curl -v -X 'GET' "http://<someIP>/testsite/#/file.html" -D header.txt -o body.txt

curl -v -X 'GET' 'http://<someIP>/testsite/#/file.html' -D header.txt -o body.txt
```

Could somebody help in answering how to escape the `#` or how to make curl to send this complete URL ?

Answer (score 0):

What's after `#` is never sent to the server in the HTTP request. That can only be read through some client side code (js for example). There is no way of making Curl send that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any other alternative of achieving this. Any other softwares that can send "#" in the url ?

Comment: No, not really. The part after the # is called fragment. The fragment isn't supposed to get to the server. Only client side code should see the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, but you can try to encode # char to a URL "safe version": %23

Here you can find more useful information: http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Comment: Yes, this can be done, but my requirement is not to encode "#" because there is one more device in between which will encode this and I am testing that.